# Run Frida hooks on system_server without a client

Tags: android, instrumentation, android-instrumentation, frida

I am using Frida and I want to hook a system_server method but without having the Frida client running on my computer. I want the entire thing to be on the device. I will have to gather the data while I am going about my day (possibly without any network connectivity either). I know about frida-gadget but frida-gadget looks under `/data/app/<APP_NAME>/lib` for its config file, and system_server has no such (writable) directory. Is there any workaround for this? I would of course also consider non-frida solutions.

Comment: The `lib` folder for a config file does not make much sense in my opinion. Are you sure frida-gadget only searches there for the config file? If yes, I would recommend to you opening an issue at [Frida Github project](https://github.com/frida/frida) as it seems to be a bug. A configuration file should be loaded from the APK itself.

Comment: Unless I misunderstood something, according too https://lief.quarkslab.com/doc/latest/tutorials/09_frida_lief.html#configuration-of-frida-gadget frida-gadget will look under that path for the configuration file. "The second requirement means that after the installation on the device, the gadget library will look for the config file in the /data/app/org.telegram.messenger-1/lib directory."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Download frida-inject from https://github.com/frida/frida/releases , push & chmod on device

```sh
./frida-inject -p `pidof system_server` -s /data/local/tmp/script.js --runtime=v8
```

Other CLI options @ https://github.com/frida/frida-core/blob/master/inject/inject.vala#L12

Edit:

For gadget you will need to repack ( & sign ) the `apk` with `frida-gadget.so` and somehow load the gadget to the memory.

The approach I use is to find the c'tor of the welcome-activity and insert the `smali` code that uses `java.lang.System.loadLibrary` to load the `so`.

The is how I find the activity

```sh
$ aapt dump badging $APK | grep "launchable-activity:" | grep -Po "(?<=name=').*?(?=')"
```

[aapt](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/aapt2) is part of android sdk

You will need to increment local variables.. and handle if it's static c'tor ( or not ) but mostly this is the smali

```
  const-string v0, "frida-gadget"
  invoke-static {v0}, Ljava/lang/System;->loadLibrary(Ljava/lang/String;)V
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I was looking for, I would however be happy to see the solution for frida-gadget as well, but its not needed. Also, just a note, --enable-jit does not seem to be a valid option for frida-inject, so if that is the case you could update your answer just to be precise. Thank you again.

Comment: NP. It was --enable-jit, updated to `runtime`. I will update tomorrow about gadget.

Comment: Does  frida-inject into system_server require rooted device?

Comment: To system_server - yes